# Populate tooltip container with inline content?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

How do I reference to look for tooltips on a same page? Currently i have the following which references an external file, but what needs to change so it knows to look on the same page?

```
        $('#tip-container').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).fadeIn(500);
        ?
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you watch tutorials about how to do tooltips?

Comment: If  no one can give me some quick pointers with my code, then i'll definitely delve deeper, I tend to try myself, ask a question if no response, then  will have to.

Comment: Right now what you have in load is 'index.html someID'. I doubt that this will return anything usefull from your server, with the space and all. Give us an example of how your retrieve the data for your tooltip from your server.

Comment: $('#tip-container').empty().load('tooltips.html ' + tooltipId).fadeIn(500); > Which is for external, but i'm looking to do the same thing, but on the same page/inline, not an external source.

Comment: So what is in tooltipId?

Comment: var tooltipId = $(this).attr("rel");   > it's the rel

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but what exactly is in the rel attribute?

Comment: The only part that refs an extenral file is this: $('#tip-container').empty().load('index.html ' + tooltipId).fadeIn(500); > So I just need to change this line, so it looks on the current page, that's all, I don't know what it would be

Comment: rel = the id of the tooltip to pull in e.e. <span class="tip" rel="tooltip_5">

Comment: So you are probably missing the proper GET var in the url you build in load(), like 'index.html?tooltip='+tooltipId   You know what I mean?

Comment: No sorry I don't: My code pulls in tooltips from an external file.

What i'm trying to do is pull them from the same page and the only problematic line is  $('#tip-container').empty().load('index.html ' + tooltipId).fadeIn(500); > this needs to change to something like  $('#tip-container').empty().load( "THECURRENTPAGE" + tooltipId).fadeIn(500); > But i don't know the exact syntax

Comment: If you don't need to call the server to get the tooltip content because it is already on the page, you don't need load(). Where exactly on your page is the tooltip data? Just use a jquery selector like var tooltipContent=$('#'+tooltipId).html(); $('#tip-container').html(tooltipContent);

Comment: Have you got an example? e.g. Do I simply replace  $('#tip-container').empty().load('index.html ' + tooltipId).fadeIn(500); with your example 100% ?

Comment: Not 1:1. It depends on the exact location of your tooltip content. Is there an element with id="tooltip_5" which actually holds the content? Then take my code. Just add the fade in: $('#tip-container').html(tooltipContent).fadeIn(500);

Comment: ok, i'll give it a try

Comment: p.s. What is this part? > html(tooltipContent). - Can't see what it's referencing

Comment: It's the jquery equivalent of javascript's innerHTML. It substitutes whatever code you have in the selected element by what the variable tooltipContent holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to call the server to get the tooltip content because it is already on the page, you don't need load(). Just use a jquery selector. Depending on the exact location of your tooltip content on your page it could look somewhat like this:

```
var tooltipContent=$('#'+tooltipId).html();
$('#tip-container').html(tooltipContent).fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: Can you expalin this aprt please? html(tooltipContent) e.g. where does this need to be defined, i've never used it before

Comment: As I said above: It's the jquery equivalent of javascript's innerHTML. It substitutes whatever code you have in the selected element (i.e. $('#tip-container') in this case) by what the variable tooltipContent holds. You don't need to empty the container, because innerHTML will just substitute whatever is in there.

Comment: @bouscher +1 for your patience

Comment: Thanks very much, appreciate patience with this one :)